# Setting PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS causes creating SparkContext to fail

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, environment-variables

a little backstory to my problem: I've been working on a spark project and recently switched my OS to Debian 9. After the switch, I reinstalled spark version `2.2.0` and started getting the following errors when running `pytest`:

```
E               Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

After googling for a little while, it looks like people have been seeing this cryptic error in two situations: 1) when trying to use spark with `java 9`; 2) when the environment variable `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` is set.

It looks like I'm in the second scenario, because I'm using java 1.8. I have written a minimal example

```
from pyspark import SparkContext                                                                                                                                 
import os

def test_whatever():
    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0 pyspark-shell'
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

It fails with said error, but when the fourth line is commented out, the test is fine (I invoke it with `pytest file_name.py`).
Removing this env variable is -- at least I don't think it is -- a solution to this problem, because it gives some important information `SparkContext`. I can't find any documentation in this regard and am lost completely.

I would appreciate any hints on this

Comment: After your edit issue is no longer reproducible.

Comment: have you resolved your error? I am stuck in there.

Answer (score 2):

Putting this at the top of my jupyter notebook works for me:

```
import os
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/'
```