# "Java gateway process exited before sending its port number" Spark & Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My Entire Codebase Looks like This:

```
import os; os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--master local[4]"
# import sparknlp as spark
from sparknlp.base import *
from sparknlp.annotator import *
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

# spark.start()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False


@app.get("/testing")
def testing():
    # sc = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp").setMaster("local[*]")).getOrCreate()
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .appName("Test Setup") \
        .getOrCreate()

    document_assembler = DocumentAssembler() \
        .setInputCol("text") \
        .setOutputCol("document")

    sentence_detector = SentenceDetector() \
        .setInputCols(["document"]) \
        .setOutputCol("sentence")

    token = Tokenizer() \
        .setInputCols(["sentence"]) \
        .setOutputCol("token") \
        .setContextChars(["(", "]", "?", "!", ".", ","])

    keywords = YakeKeywordExtraction() \
        .setInputCols(["token"]) \
        .setOutputCol("keywords") \
        .setThreshold(0.6) \
        .setMinNGrams(2) \
        .setNKeywords(10)

    pipeline = Pipeline().setStages([
        document_assembler,
        sentence_detector,
        token,
        keywords
    ])
    data = spark.createDataFrame([[
        "Sources tell us that Google is acquiring Kaggle, a platform that hosts data science and machine learning competitions. Details about the transaction remain somewhat vague, but given that Google is hosting its Cloud Next conference in San Francisco this week, the official announcement could come as early as tomorrow. Reached by phone, Kaggle co-founder CEO Anthony Goldbloom declined to deny that the acquisition is happening. Google itself declined 'to comment on rumors'. Kaggle, which has about half a million data scientists on its platform, was founded by Goldbloom  and Ben Hamner in 2010. The service got an early start and even though it has a few competitors like DrivenData, TopCoder and HackerRank, it has managed to stay well ahead of them by focusing on its specific niche. The service is basically the de facto home for running data science and machine learning competitions. With Kaggle, Google is buying one of the largest and most active communities for data scientists - and with that, it will get increased mindshare in this community, too (though it already has plenty of that thanks to Tensorflow and other projects). Kaggle has a bit of a history with Google, too, but that's pretty recent. Earlier this month, Google and Kaggle teamed up to host a $100,000 machine learning competition around classifying YouTube videos. That competition had some deep integrations with the Google Cloud Platform, too. Our understanding is that Google will keep the service running - likely under its current name. While the acquisition is probably more about Kaggle's community than technology, Kaggle did build some interesting tools for hosting its competition and 'kernels', too. On Kaggle, kernels are basically the source code for analyzing data sets and developers can share this code on the platform (the company previously called them 'scripts'). Like similar competition-centric sites, Kaggle also runs a job board, too. It's unclear what Google will do with that part of the service. According to Crunchbase, Kaggle raised $12.5 million (though PitchBook says it's $12.75) since its   launch in 2010. Investors in Kaggle include Index Ventures, SV Angel, Max Levchin, NaRavikant, Google chie economist Hal Varian, Khosla Ventures and Yuri Milner"
    ]]).toDF("text")
    result = pipeline.fit(data).transform(data)

    scores = result \
        .selectExpr("explode(arrays_zip(keywords.result, keywords.metadata)) as resultTuples") \
        .selectExpr("resultTuples['0'] as keyword", "resultTuples['1'].score as score")

    print(scores.orderBy("score").show(5, truncate=False))
```

I am trying to export keywords from the text given using the SparkNLP Library. My Operating System is Macos with Apple Silicon Chip.

I am currently following https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/api/python/reference/autosummary/sparknlp.annotator.YakeKeywordExtraction.html article to retrieve keywords but as soon as I run the script and hit the API it gives me an error, The entire Log is given below:

```
Error: Missing application resource.

Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file | R file> [app arguments]
Usage: spark-submit --kill [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit --status [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit run-example [options] example-class [example args]

Options:
  --master MASTER_URL         spark://host:port, mesos://host:port, yarn,
                              k8s://https://host:port, or local (Default: local[*]).
  --deploy-mode DEPLOY_MODE   Whether to launch the driver program locally ("client") or
                              on one of the worker machines inside the cluster ("cluster")
                              (Default: client).
  --class CLASS_NAME          Your application's main class (for Java / Scala apps).
  --name NAME                 A name of your application.
  --jars JARS                 Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver
                              and executor classpaths.
  --packages                  Comma-separated list of maven coordinates of jars to include
                              on the driver and executor classpaths. Will search the local
                              maven repo, then maven central and any additional remote
                              repositories given by --repositories. The format for the
                              coordinates should be groupId:artifactId:version.
  --exclude-packages          Comma-separated list of groupId:artifactId, to exclude while
                              resolving the dependencies provided in --packages to avoid
                              dependency conflicts.
  --repositories              Comma-separated list of additional remote repositories to
                              search for the maven coordinates given with --packages.
  --py-files PY_FILES         Comma-separated list of .zip, .egg, or .py files to place
                              on the PYTHONPATH for Python apps.
  --files FILES               Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working
                              directory of each executor. File paths of these files
                              in executors can be accessed via SparkFiles.get(fileName).
  --archives ARCHIVES         Comma-separated list of archives to be extracted into the
                              working directory of each executor.

  --conf, -c PROP=VALUE       Arbitrary Spark configuration property.
  --properties-file FILE      Path to a file from which to load extra properties. If not
                              specified, this will look for conf/spark-defaults.conf.

  --driver-memory MEM         Memory for driver (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1024M).
  --driver-java-options       Extra Java options to pass to the driver.
  --driver-library-path       Extra library path entries to pass to the driver.
  --driver-class-path         Extra class path entries to pass to the driver. Note that
                              jars added with --jars are automatically included in the
                              classpath.

  --executor-memory MEM       Memory per executor (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1G).

  --proxy-user NAME           User to impersonate when submitting the application.
                              This argument does not work with --principal / --keytab.

  --help, -h                  Show this help message and exit.
  --verbose, -v               Print additional debug output.
  --version,                  Print the version of current Spark.

 Cluster deploy mode only:
  --driver-cores NUM          Number of cores used by the driver, only in cluster mode
                              (Default: 1).

 Spark standalone or Mesos with cluster deploy mode only:
  --supervise                 If given, restarts the driver on failure.

 Spark standalone, Mesos or K8s with cluster deploy mode only:
  --kill SUBMISSION_ID        If given, kills the driver specified.
  --status SUBMISSION_ID      If given, requests the status of the driver specified.

 Spark standalone, Mesos and Kubernetes only:
  --total-executor-cores NUM  Total cores for all executors.

 Spark standalone, YARN and Kubernetes only:
  --executor-cores NUM        Number of cores used by each executor. (Default: 1 in
                              YARN and K8S modes, or all available cores on the worker
                              in standalone mode).

 Spark on YARN and Kubernetes only:
  --num-executors NUM         Number of executors to launch (Default: 2).
                              If dynamic allocation is enabled, the initial number of
                              executors will be at least NUM.
  --principal PRINCIPAL       Principal to be used to login to KDC.
  --keytab KEYTAB             The full path to the file that contains the keytab for the
                              principal specified above.

 Spark on YARN only:
  --queue QUEUE_NAME          The YARN queue to submit to (Default: "default").
      
[2022-04-12 07:47:30,133] ERROR in app: Exception on /testing [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chinmay/Downloads/Topic-Exploration/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/chinmay/Downloads/Topic-Exploration/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/chinmay/Downloads/Topic-Exploration/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/chinmay/Downloads/Topic-Exploration/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/chinmay/Downloads/Topic-Exploration/sparknlp2.py", line 19, in testing
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
  File "/Users/chinmay/Downloads/Topic-Exploration/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/Users/chinmay/Downloads/Topic-Exploration/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 384, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users/chinmay/Downloads/Topic-Exploration/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 144, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/Users/chinmay/Downloads/Topic-Exploration/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 331, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/Users/chinmay/Downloads/Topic-Exploration/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 108, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I was having Java 17 installed earlier and then I installed Java 8 but no Help.
My current JAVA_HOME variables value is `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

I am currently new to Python & NLP Operations, Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How did you run this python file?

Comment: python3 main.py

This was one way to do this. Other way I used was to run it using Pycharm

Comment: Looks like you're experiencing the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742570/setting-pyspark-submit-args-causes-creating-sparkcontext-to-fail). Try commenting out the first line of your program.